# Select then parse using substring and cast gives different result from computation

Tags: sql-server, parsing, casting, substring, rounding

I parsed a string which I use substring to get the last 11 i think numbers of characters. I accomplished that one but when I use cast and round it gives a different result from the manual computation I did.

Here's my query

```
SELECT round(cast(SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1R,141117003059,A,1420.4629N,12058.7028E,0.0,77,0.9,20000006;2R,141117003059,11,98.3,12.58,04.10,282098820.9', 123,11)as float)/3600, 0, 1)
```

This gives me a result of 583. But when I try to manually compute using the computation below

```
282098820.9 / 3600
```

The result is

```
78360.7835
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What value does `SELECT cast(SUBSTRING('351856040520298,241111;1R,141117003059,A,1420.4629N,12058.7028E,0.0,77,0.9,20000006;2R,141117003059,11,98.3,12.58,04.10,282098820.9', 123,11)as float)` return for you?  It looks like `2098820.9` to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `SUBSTRING`. It only returns `2098820.9` instead of `282098820.9`. Try using `RIGHT` to extract the last 11 characters.

```
SELECT round(cast(right('351856040520298,241111;1R,141117003059,A,1420.4629N,12058.7028E,0.0,77,0.9,20000006;2R,141117003059,11,98.3,12.58,04.10,282098820.9', 11)as float)/3600, 0, 1)
```